# jQuery: track multiple events in central location

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Disclaimer: I am a designer with little jQuery knowledge. I will work with a JavaScript developer to realise this, but need to be able to write a detailed specification of my requirement.**

I am looking to develop a platform which will track user behaviour via jQuery events API. Events, such as whether a user ‘points-and-clicks’ or <kbd>tab</kbd>’s to proceeding form fields will be scored, e.g. ‘point-and-click’ gets a **-1** and <kbd>tab</kbd> gets a **2**.

What is the best way of keeping track of all these event scores? My initial thought is an integer variable which increases and decreases in number depending upon user behaviour. The platform must also be able to:

- be developed into a cookie
- the value of the variable (if this is the best method) will inform which content to deliver to the viewstate via AJAX

I am happy to receive code snippets and/or written specification suggestions on how best to handle this.

Comment: why you don't just tell her as you told us , tell her a story about the secnario ... too much details on the task kills the creativity Trust me

Comment: When you mention Ajax it seems to indicate you want to dynamically change the content while she/he is surfing the page? Whether you want to store the scores as a single integer or a list of all scores depends on your needs. Storing the value in a cookie is easy.

Comment: @Sedz I understand that view, and thank you for your contribution. I guess if I get a clear steer and nod in the right direction then I may try to prototype this myself so that I can articulate to some extent programmatically what I wish to achieve.

Comment: @kjetilh yes, content will dynamically change while the user is surfing the page (but unobtrusively, not main content, but help tip content).

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your need is *to be able to write a detailed specification of your requirements* then copy/paste your question. It's ok like this.

Or make it more clear by removing your questionnings. If you're writing required specs, don't try to answer on how it should be done, just ask for what has to be done.

> Track user behaviour via jQuery events API. Events, such as whether a
>   user ‘points-and-clicks’ or <kbd>tab</kbd>’s to proceeding form
>   fields.

You can add extra 'project management' infos like

- date required
- accessibility scope
- some web development nice to write for a designer but useless for a developer stuff
- budget
- data chart / data flow
- inputs/outputs